# Spring boot integration of sleuth with jms

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, spring-cloud-sleuth

In my spring boot application the spring sleuth only works with my rest service and not with @JmsListener. All the answer on the internet date back in  2016-17. Is their a way for Spring Cloud Sleuth to instrument all @JmsListener annotated methods in order to propagate tracing information ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such instrumentation coming out of the box at the moment. You can follow this issue https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/issues/584 cause once it's done in Brave it will be most likely added in Sleuth.

Comment: I was looking at different post- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/151 The solution mentioned here doesn't works if I put the same code in my method which has JMSListener annotated.

Comment: @marcin Does slueth provides auto instrumentation if spring integration is used for jms(activemq) activity or the support for jmslistener without spring integration is available now ? I read the docs, support for jmslistener is mentioned. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_spring_jms I couldn't find any example for spring slueth + jms, so quite confused is it auto instrumented or not.

Comment: It should. If you have a sample that doesn't work, please upload the sample somewhere at GitHub and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Instead to `JmsTemplate` to send messages and `JmsListener` to receive messages, use spring cloud stream to send and receive messages and everything will be automatically taken care of.

sent messages:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;

@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class MessageSender {

    @Autowired
    private final Source source;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void test() {
        this.source.output().send(new GenericMessage<>("Dummy Message"));
        log.info("Message sent!");
    }    

}
```

Receive messages:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink;

@Slf4j
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class TranscribedDataListener {

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void handleMessage(String message) {
        log.info("Message received: {}", message);
    }

}
```

I'm using azure service bus, my .yml configuration is:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      servicebus:
        connection-string: service-bus-url
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: topic-name
          group: topic-group
        output:
          destination: topic-name
```